# Have refinable managed properties updated without reindexing lists, in SharePoint

Tags: list, search, properties, sharepoint-2013, managed

I am using Sharepoint 2013 on premise and have a number of FAQ lists in a site collection.

To aggregate them as one FAQ I have a search page, where all the FAQ items (of content type FAQ item) can be searched. On my search page I wanted to be able to filter on topics tags, so I have mapped one of the columns (Topic) as refinable managed property (RefinableString01). It all seemed to work pretty well...

However, the topics for a new FAQ item will not be displayed unless I go and reindex that particular list where new the FAQ item has been added.
(List Settings - > Advanced Settings -> Reindex list (to reindex all of the content during the next scheduled crawl))

Since the idea with many FAQ lists is that different groups should be reponsible for the information in their FAQ list, I have no control over when new FAQ items are added and if nobody runs the reindex the FAQ search page will not be usable.

Is there a better way of getting this to work, without a lot of maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked on the server that the crawl service was running properly. I could see that incremental crawls were done at regular intervals. Still, that did not make the topics of new FAQ items being displayed.

So, we decided to perform a full crawl and after that full crawl it seems like new FAQ topics are being picked up during the incremental crawls. So, a full crawl solved this issue.